# Skip DNS lookup in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

For an app I'm writing I want to completely avoid DNS host name resolution: I'm using numeric IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and I have no use for lookups. I've googled a bit but I can't find a class that allows me to open a connection without causing a DNS request to occur. Any hints?

TIA

Comment: Well, if you do use numeric IPs you won't do a DNS lookup... What's the problem?

Comment: InetSocketAddress#getAddress returns null if unresolved

Comment: Add a code example with the failing use of the numeric IP-address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke `InetAddress.getByName()` with a name that's not really a name, but is an IP address, Java won't perform the DNS lookup.

Another option is to use `InetAddress.getByAddress()` like so:

```
byte[] numericAddress = new byte[]{127,0,0,1};
InetAddress.getByAddress(numericAddress); //Will return an InetAddress that points to 127.0.0.1
```